# Replace in mysql database

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a question about replacement a particular string in mysql but one part of the string is is changed every time e.g

```
"(my string to replace 1224:2)"
"(my string to replace 134:4)"
"(my string to replace 1824:9)"
"(my string to replace 14:2)"
```

I can change first part of string using this query

```
update dle_post set short_story = replace(short_story,'(my','( my');
```

but how to replace other parts like `1224:2)` , or `14:2)` or any other part that ends with a number `1,2,3..` and a `)`. I can not use bracket `")"` because it is used on many other places.

Comment: use regex replace : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Comment: There are only 10 combinations. Why can't you just place them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant way, but...

```
update dle_post 
set short_story = 
    replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
    short_story,
    '0)','0 )'),'1)','1 )'),'2)','2 )'),'3)','3 )'),'4)','4 )'),'5)','5 )'),'6)','6 )'),'7)','7 )'),'8)','8 )'),'9)','9 )');
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions should work in this kind of case. Take a look related question: [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Comment: if there is any tutorial of regx for bigners ?